# How to write comments in JSTL properties files

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere, jstl

I'd like to know how to write comments in properties file that is used like this

`PF47=Ankomstdatum måste anges innan SIS kan avslutas. # AF PCT`

`#` is supposed to mean a comment but when I render the messages with fmt format JSTL tag output includes the comment. Do comments in properties file have to be on a separate line?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if java-property files only allow comments on separate lines, so you need to write

```
# AF PCT
PF47=Ankomstdatum måste anges innan SIS kan avslutas.
```

Answer (score 1):

The format is described in the [java.util.Properties documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29). And yes, the `#` character is only considered as the start of a comment if it's the first non-whitespace character of the line.